# How to fill two inputs with same function and how to add max value?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this increase/decrease function, and I have 2 problems with :

1.I need to fill 2 inputs with same value, ex: if `input` has value = 1, `inputs2` should has same value.

2.I need to add max value of 24 for `var el` or `input`. I tried with `max="10"` on input, but doesn't working anymore. Please, feel free to answer.

```js
function increaseValue() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}

function decreaseValue() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
```

```html
 <img class="left-down" src="images/clock/left-down.png" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue()" value="Decrease Value"> 
 <img class="left-up" src="images/clock/left-up.png" id="increase" onclick="increaseValue()" value="Increase Value"> 
 
 <input type='Number' id='number' value='0' class='qty' max="10" min="0" />
       <input type='Number' id='number2' value='0' class='qty' max="10" min="0" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function increaseValue() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  if(value>24){return}
  document.getElementById('number').value = value;
  document.getElementById('number2').value = value;
}

function decreaseValue() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('number').value = value;
  document.getElementById('number2').value = value;
}
```

```html
 <img class="left-down" src="images/clock/left-down.png" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue()" value="Decrease Value"> 
 <img class="left-up" src="images/clock/left-up.png" id="increase" onclick="increaseValue()" value="Increase Value"> 
 
 <input type='Number' id='number' value='0' class='qty' max="10" min="0" />
       <input type='Number' id='number2' value='0' class='qty' max="10" min="0" />
```

Comment: Seems like is working, but how can I add max-value 24 for that?

Comment: @Andrew try now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same function to update both values like this:-

JS

```
function updateValue(action) {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    if (action === 'increase') {
        value++;
        if (value > 24) return;
    }
    if (action === 'decrease') {
        value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
        value--;  
    }
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
    document.getElementById('number2').value = value;
}
```

HTML

```
<img class="left-down" src="images/clock/left-down.png" id="decrease" onclick="updateValue('decrease')" value="Decrease Value"> 
 <img class="left-up" src="images/clock/left-up.png" id="increase" onclick="updateValue('increase')" value="Increase Value"> 

<input type='Number' id='number' value='0' class='qty' max="10" min="0" />
<input type='Number' id='number2' value='0' class='qty' max="10" min="0" />
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I already found the solve for my problem :) but thank you !

Comment: Sure, thanks. I think your question was, how to use the same function to update both values?

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1 style="color:green;">   
        GeeksForGeeks   
    </h1> 
<input type='text' id='id1' /> 
<br> 
<br> 
<button onclick="gfg_Run()"> 
    click to set 
</button> 
<p id="GFG_DOWN" style="color:green;  
                        font-size: 20px; 
                        font-weight: bold;"> 
</p> 

    **var el_down = document.getElementById("GFG_DOWN"); 
    var inputF = document.getElementById("id1"); 

    function gfg_Run() { 
        inputF.setAttribute('value', 'defaultValue'); 
        el_down.innerHTML =  
               "Value = " + "'" + inputF.value + "'"; 
    }**
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code will also warn user, if they explicitily type value more than 24.

```
function updateValue(action) {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    if (action === 'increase') {
        value++;
        if (value > 24) return;
    }
    if (action === 'decrease') {
        value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
        value--;  
    }
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
    document.getElementById('number2').value = value;
}

function syncValue(inputBox){
    let firstInput = document.getElementById('number');
    let secondInput = document.getElementById('number2');

    if(inputBox === 'primary'){
        secondInput.value = firstInput.value;
    }
    if(inputBox === 'sencondry'){
        firstInput.value = secondInput.value;
    }
    if(firstInput.value > 24 || secondInput.value > 24 ){
        firstInput.style.border = "1px solid red";
        secondInput.style.border = "1px solid red";
    }else{
        firstInput.style.border = "1px solid grey";
        secondInput.style.border = "1px solid grey";
    }
}
```

Added blur event to your html and changed max value to 24

```
<input type='Number' id='number' value='0' class='qty' min="0" max="24" onblur="syncValue('primary')" />
<input type='Number' id='number2' value='0' class='qty' min="0" max="24" onblur="syncValue('sencondry')" />
```